# Select only one check box ; RecyclerView; Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

It's my code and I want to choose only one checkbox, and if another checkbox is selected I want that this convert in uncheked

```
class AuthorizationFormAdapter(lista: List<Procedures>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AuthorizationFormAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val lista: List<Procedures>? = lista
    lateinit var array: BooleanArray

    class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val text: TextView? = null
        val checkBox: CheckBox? = null
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_authform, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lista!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.auth_name.text = lista!![position].name_procedure
        holder.view.cb_auth.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.view.cb_auth.isChecked) {
                holder.view.cb_auth.isSelected = true
            } else if (!holder.view.cb_auth.isChecked) {
                holder.view.cb_auth.isChecked = false
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And Xml is only one checkBox and textView  in my card
I will be very grateful with your help

Comment: I see only one `CheckBox`. Where is another?

Comment: Md. Asaduzzaman I do a recyclerview

Comment: Add your `Procedures` class

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a field in your `Procedures` to store the `checked/unchecked` state

```
var isChecked: Boolean = false
```

Then inside your adapter store `lastCheckedPosition` and `unchecked` when user select other.

```
class AuthorizationFormAdapter(lista: List<Procedures>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AuthorizationFormAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var lastCheckedPosition: Int = 0

    ....

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val procedure = lista!![position]

        holder.view.auth_name.text = procedure.name_procedure
        holder.view.cb_auth.isChecked = procedure.is_checked

        holder.view.cb_auth.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked -> 

            if(isChecked) {
                lista!![lastCheckedPosition].is_checked = false
                lastCheckedPosition = position
            }

            lista!![position].is_checked = isChecked
            notifyDataSetChanged() // This is important to reload the list
        }

    }
}
```